# Conditional mean and orthogonality

Tags: time-series, conditional-expectation

I am stuck with the proof that the conditional mean satisfies the orthogonality conditions. Say, we have Y as a scalar random variable with finite variance and X as random vector. Conditional mean of Y given X is then: E(Y|X).

Question: How can we show that the conditional mean satisfies the following orthogonality conditions (using LIE):
E[Y-E(Y|X)] = 0 and
E{[Y-E(Y|X)]k(X)} = 0
for any real-valued function k for which the expectation above is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia has proofs of the law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) covering your first case as  $E[Y-E(Y\mid X)] = 0 $ is the same as $E[E(Y \mid X)] = E[Y]$

For your second case, $$E\{[Y-E(Y|X)]k(X)\} = E\{[Y-E(Y|X)]k(X) \mid X\} \\= E\{E[Y-E(Y|X)\mid X]k(X) \mid X \} = E\{0 \times k(X)\mid X \} \\= E\{0 \mid X\}= E\{0\} = 0$$